# GLSL compilation failed but no error message

Tags: c++, glsl

I am trying to create a basic shader class in c++ but i have some problems with GLSL (first time using it).

Here is my cpp file:

```
#include "shader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

shader::shader(){
    int status;

    std::string line, full;
    std::ifstream fragmentfile("fragment.fs");
    if(fragmentfile.is_open()){
        while(fragmentfile.good()){
            getline(fragmentfile, line);
            full.append(line + '\n');
        }
        fragmentfile.close();
    }
    static const char* fragment_source = full.c_str();

    std::cout << fragment_source << std::endl;

    program_object = glCreateProgram();
    shaderref = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    glShaderSource(shaderref, 1, &fragment_source, NULL);

    glCompileShader(shaderref);
    glGetShaderiv(shaderref, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if(status != GL_TRUE){
        std::cout << "The shader could not be compiled\n" << std::endl;
        char errorlog[500] = {'\0'};
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderref, 500, 0, errorlog);
        std::cout << "Error: " << errorlog << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "The shader could be compiled\n" << std::endl;

    glAttachShader(program_object, shaderref);

    glLinkProgram(program_object);
    glGetProgramiv(program_object, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if(status != GL_TRUE){
        std::cout << "The shader could not be linked\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "The shader could be linked\n";
}
```

fragment.fs:

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The runtime output is just:

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}


The shader could not be compiled

Error: 
The shader could not be linked
```

No error at all.

OS: Linux

OK, I found now sth. interesting out by reading the API: glGetShaderiv won't change int status "If an error is generated" and that's the case here, I'll see what I can find furthermore.

Something was really bugged, creating a new Project in Code::Blocks fixxed it magically.

Comment: How did you compile and link your program? What happened when you did?

Comment: I just linked the program against -lX11 and -lGL with g++ (Code::Blocks as IDE).

Comment: What is it with people reading files line by line and concatenating them together? Have you not heard of how to read the *entire thing*? Or is there some terrible tutorial out there encouraging this garbage code?

Comment: Yeah I've seen the file read in a glsl tutorial and thought too a function to read the _entire thing_ would be useful. :)

Comment: Please edit your question with the *exact* command-line you ust to compile and link your code as well as the output.

Comment: @NicolBolas Good point. That whole while loop should be replaced by a single line of code...

Comment: These are the commands to compile the shader:

g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -O3      -c /home/florian/FlEngine/shader.cpp -o obj/Release/shader.o

g++  -o bin/Release/FlEngine obj/Release/main.o obj/Release/renderengine.o obj/Release/shader.o   -s  -lX11 -lGL

Comment: Regarding reading shaders into code. I'm a fan of the 'stringify' macro trick:

Comment: trick is:#define STRINGIFY(A) #A

static const char* PatternGinghamVertexShader =
STRINGIFY(
          attribute vec4 Position; ...etc. more shader code here ...); From Rideout book on openGLES in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You have the standard 'off by one' error on reading the file (by using `while (fragmentfile.good())`) which duplicates the last line of the file.  So the shader you attempt to compile is:

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
}
```

which fails (though why you don't see a useful error message in the infolog is unclear.)

This is a common error in both C and C++, repeated in many places.  When you have a loop that reads things until the end of a file, your loop test should ALWAYS be on the read operation, and NEVER on the stream flags which don't get set until AFTER an operation attempts to read past the end of the file:

```
while(getline(fragmentfile, line)) {
    full.append(line + '\n');
}
```

Alternately, follow Nicol Bolas's advice and read the entire file at once:

```
getline(fragmentfile, full, '\0');
```

This assumes the fragment program does not contain any NUL (`'\0'`) bytes, which it cannot if it's a valid fragement program.